# Punctuation/Pause character in IPA

Tags: phonetics, ipa

Is there any way to get breaks between words in a sentence written using IPA?

I have the following IPA sentence:

*/gaɦi ʃammer gan manuʃer tʃee naɦi kitʃʰu bɔɽɔ naɦi kitʃʰu mɔɦian/*

Now, when i play it using amazon polly SSML, the voice goes through the sentence way too fast.

I was wondering whether there is a way to put punctuation or break in between words.

Comment: Most voice synthesizers should have an option for that, shouldn't they?

Comment: Not IPA, but within Amazon Polly you can use the <break> and <prosody> tags.

Answer (score 1):

A double vertical bar is often used in transcriptions to indicate a major intonational phrase boundary, and a single one to indicate a minor one.

- /stɒp ‖ bɪfɔ: sʌmwʌŋ geʔs hɜ:t/

Comment: How do you make it look less like a click consonant?